# Jetty 8 Server Startup using only Command Prompt

Tags: java, jetty, command-prompt

I am new to using the Jetty server. For starting `Jetty v8.1` Using the command prompt, I need to navigate to the `jetty-distribution-8.1.16.v20140903` folder and run the command: `java -jar start.jar`.

In case I don't navigate to the `jetty-distribution-8.1.16.v20140903` folder and try to start the command using: `java -jar C:\jetty-distribution-8.1.16.v20140903\start.jar` then I get an `FileNotFoundException` :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No XML configuration files specified in start.con
fig or command line.
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:502)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)

Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information
```

What are the files does it looks for while starting the server? Please let me know how to start the jetty server without navigating to the distribution folder.

**Edit:**

When I tried this command:

```
java -Djetty.home= C:\jetty-distribution-8.1.16.v20140903 -jar C:\jetty-distribution-8.1.16.v20140903/start.jar
```

I got the below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\jetty-distribution-8.1.16.v20140
903
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: C:\jetty-distribution-8.1.16.v20140903.  Program
will exit.
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
java -Djetty.home=C:\jetty-distribution-8.1.15.v20140411 -jar C:\jetty-distribution-8.1.15.v20140411/start.jar
```

Comment: I tried setting the jetty home by modifying the command by got the NoClassDefFoundError. (updated the post with new command and error message) Please suggest

Comment: Remove the space after -Djetty.home=

Comment: there is an space between: -Djetty.home= C:\

Comment: Thanks; it works fine now. Please confirm whether the same command will work for higher versions of jetty as well or not (such as Jetty v9, etc). I don't have JDK 7 in my system hence unable to verify the same.

Comment: With jetty9, we need set jetty.base and jetty.home like this: java -Djetty.base=jetty-distribution-9.1.2.v20140210 -Djetty.home=jetty-distribution-9.1.2.v20140210 -jar jetty-distribution-9.1.2.v20140210/start.jar. For more, check: java -jar start.jar --help.

Comment: @刘旭_ that is not advised (having home and base the same), you also now have a bad `user.dir` that many 3rd party libraries rely on.

Comment: Yeah, specify user.dir with another path would be a better practice.

Comment: @刘旭_ if you are going down that path of just specifying everything on the command line, don't forget `java.io.tmpdir` too (along with a host of others)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Jetty documentation [Running Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-running-jetty.html) the correct way to start the Jetty server is:

```
cd $JETTY_HOME
java -jar start.jar
```

Do you have `$JETTY_HOME` defined?

If so you can just write a small script, eg called `RunJetty` or `Jetty` that contains the above commands. The script could even restore the current directory as well ...

Comment: Jetty's `start.jar` does not use or look for a system environment variable called `JETTY_HOME` (only the `jetty.sh` does, which you didn't use in your example)

Comment: @Joakim according to the documentation that is the recommended way to start Jetty ... exactly those 2 lines

Comment: yes, and that reference in that documentation is merely a reference to a location on disk, the second you jumped to the assumption that the environment variable needs to exist is where the mistake was made.

Comment: ok, i fixed up that documentation to not cause that confusion again.

Answer (score 0):

The startup of Jetty 8 is old and now very different than Jetty 9.

*Important Note: [Jetty 8 is soon EOL](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html), would highly encourage upgrading to Jetty 9 pronto.*

For Jetty 8, the `${jetty.home}` path is where everything takes place (aka your `jetty-distribution` directory).

For Jetty 8, it looks for a `${jetty.home}/start.ini` and then starts to build up the command line, xml files, properties, start.d OPTIONS declarations, etc to start your environment.

For Jetty 9, this is radically different, there is a clear split between `${jetty.home}` the unmodified distribution, and a new `${jetty.base}` where you configure for your specific jetty instance. You can even have multiple `${jetty.base}` directories for different instances.  There is even support for a tiered `${jetty.base}` declaration to further separate roles in an organization (ops installs jetty-dist into a common `${jetty.home}`, configures a infrastructure `${jetty.base}` to handle logging and monitoring, and the application is in its own `${jetty.base}`, at which point all 3 are combined to form the configuration that instance uses)